# Accessing bot in azure in android

Tags: c#, android, azure, botframework

I have deployed a bot in azure. Bot is written in C# using microsoft bot framework.
I am able to communicate with it using Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator after providing the azure URL, App Id and App Secret.
How to communicate with the bot from android?
Is there a URL to communicate with it like a REST Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a bot registered to BotFramework, you can try to configure the Web Chat channel :

- Log in to [Bot Framework](http://dev.botframework.com)
- Go to "your bots"
- Click on the bot you've registered
- Click on "Edit" next to “Web Chat” in the Channels
- Generate your Web Chat Secrets (a blue button)
- Tick "enable this bot on web chat"
- Take note of the secret and embed tag

Then, take out the link from the iframe, (you'll get something like this : https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YourBotID?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE )
Replace YOUR_SECRET_HERE with the secret you previously took

Then, browse the final link from your phone / anywhere.

Comment: What if the bot is not registered in bot framework? I just deployed it in azure.

Comment: If it isn't registered, you can register it for free, since you already deployed it to azure etc. But I don't see how you'd do this without registering, since the ChatConnector's purpose is basically to connect channels through the bot framework or the emulator. Even the classic [Rest API](http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/connector/#navtitle) needs to be registered on bot framework

Answer (score 0):

@SandeepMenon, There is a [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bot-framework-made-better-with-azure/) which introduces how to integate Azure Logic Apps with a Bot Web App using Bot Framework API hosted on Azure and supply [the sample project](https://github.com/jeffhollan/BotFrameworkSample) on GitHub.

I think you can try to refer to the blog and use the Azure [Logic App as callable endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-http-endpoint/), then to communicate with bot from android is only implementation for calling the http endpoints from android.